# Parallel vectors relation

Tags: vectors

I have a very short and probably very stupid question. While doing an exercise I bumped into the following relation:

If two vectors $\vec{x}$ and $\vec{y}$ are parallel, then $\vec{x} =$ $     <\vec{x},\vec{y}>\vec{y}$.

I don't know if this relation always holds, but if it does, can someone maybe verify for me how? It looks super easy but I can't seem to figure it out.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does $\vec y$ have unit length?  Otherwise, it is false.  Take $\vec y =(1,1)$ and $\vec x = (2,2)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation $$\vec{x} =<\vec{x},\vec{y}>\vec{y}$$ is not true in general even if the vectors are parallel because the norms do not match.

However we can fix it by slightly changing it to $$\vec{x} =\frac {<\vec{x},\vec{y}>}{||y||^2}\vec{y}$$ which is true if the vectors are parallel.

Note that the vectors the same directions and and in case of being parallel they also have the same norm.

Answer (score 1):

The projection of vector $\vec x$ onto vector $\vec y$ is $\dfrac {<\vec x,\vec y>}{<\vec y,\vec y>}\vec y$.  When $\vec x$ and $\vec y$ are parallel, this is $\vec x$.  If $\vec y$ is a unit vector, then $<\vec y,\vec y>=1$ and the relation you gave holds.

—————————————-

If $\vec y=c\vec x$, then the projection is $\dfrac{<\vec x,c \vec x>}{<c\vec x,c\vec x >}c\vec x=\vec x$